# Query in Joining Two Databases in Two Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query which joins Microsoft and Oracle (as Linked) but this query takes long time (more than 1 hour) .  but I run every joins separately , does not took long ( less than 10sec each). Is there any way I can re-do the query . e.g. running different part of query then getting a combined result .

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.NMR, B.ADDRESS, C.TEL
FROM ALPHA A

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ADDRESS, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCA, 'SELECT ADDRESS, NMR FROM tblADDRESS') B ON B.NMR = A.NMR

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TEL, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCT, 'SELECT TEL, NMR FROM tblTEL') C ON C.NMR = A.NMR
```

I want to run separately

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.NMR FROM ALPHA A
```

then

```
SELECT TEL, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCT, 'SELECT TEL, NMR FROM tblTEL')
```

then

```
SELECT TEL, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCT, 'SELECT TEL, NMR FROM tblTEL')
```

then

get the result

Comment: Running JOINs across servers is always a bad idea from the performance point of view. Maybe you can extract the information you want from the external servers first into two temporary tables and then join these tables into your main query?

Comment: I think you have a copy/paste issue... the second `Select` is the exact same as the third `Select`. But, why don't you use temp tables for the 2 open query selects and join the `Alpha` table to the temp tables?

Comment: Yes, and there are also two brackets `)` missing in the first query ... but the point remains: collect data into temporary tables first, then join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of a performance improvment it will be but can try using a CTE. Part of me thinks this will do the exact same thing but if you are saying they all run faster separately maybe it will help.

```
with data1 as (SELECT A.NAME, A.NMR FROM ALPHA A),
data2 as(SELECT ADDRESS, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCA, 'SELECT ADDRESS, NMR FROM tblADDRESS'),
data3 as(SELECT TEL, NMR FROM OPENQUERY(ORCT, 'SELECT TEL, NMR FROM tblTEL')

SELECT A.NAME, A.NMR, B.ADDRESS, C.TEL
FROM data1 A
left join data2 B ON B.NMR = A.NMR
left join data3 C ON C.NMR = A.NMR
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to load each result from the OPENQUERY's into their own temp tables and then join the temp tables to the "local" table.

```
SELECT 
    ADDRESS
    ,NMR 
INTO #ORCA 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ORCA, 'SELECT ADDRESS, NMR FROM tblADDRESS')

SELECT 
    TEL
    ,NMR
INTO #ORCT
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ORCT, 'SELECT TEL, NMR FROM tblTEL')

SELECT 
    A.NAME
    ,A.NMR
    ,ORCA.ADDRESS
    ,ORCT.TEL
FROM
    ALPHA A

        LEFT JOIN #ORCA ORCA
        ON A.NMR = ORCA.NMR

        LEFT JOIN #ORCT ORCT
        ON A.NMR = ORCT.NMR
```

Comment: hi, I like this concept . I will have a go with this. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine . Took. 20sec.  Only, question is how this one is GDN's .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite follow the question, but it's true that cross-server joins tend to be very inefficient. Probably your best approach would be to `SELECT` the subset of data you need from the remote server into a local temporary table, then `JOIN` to the temporary table.

```
select * into #remoteAddress from openquery (orca, 'select id, address, nmr from tblAddress');
select * into #remoteTelephone from openquery (orcb, 'select tel, nmr from tblTel');
select a.name, a.nmr, b.address, c.tel
 from alpha a
 left join #remoteAddress b
  on a.nmr = b.nmr
 left join #remoteTelephone c
  on a.nmr = c.nmr
```

The main point is to avoid running the `JOIN` across servers. Get the data you need into temporary tables and join to them instead.

Comment: hi, looks great. I will try .